# Hiding part of the url in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, query-string

I was thinking if there is a way to hide part of the url in PHP/ Zend Framework 2. Something like this:

```
sitename.com/something/?inviter=1234&id=1
```

But I'd like to hide the part with the &id=1 somehow, so that when the url is copied and entered by the user, it would look like this:

```
sitename.com/something/?inviter=1234
```

And on the other side I can do something like this:

```
$id = $_GET["id"])
```

Is this possible to do, if so, how? Maybe there is something close to what I'm looking for to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it only with Cookie or Session techniques. But it will work only for one user during one session.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse and rebuild the url using [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.parse-url.php), [http_build_url](https://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.http-build-url.php), with [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), and [http_build_str](https://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.http-build-str.php).

For example:

```
/**
 * Transform a url using a whitelist of query-string keys
 */
function transformUrlKeepQueryKeys($url, array $whitelist)
{
    // Break the given url into parts
    $parts = parse_url($url);

    // Break the parts into key-value pairs
    $query = $parts['query'];
    parse_str($query, $queryParts);

    // Unset all unwanted keys
    foreach (array_keys($queryParts) as $k) {
        if (!in_array($k, $whitelist)) {
            unset($queryParts[$k]);
        }
    }

    // rebuild the url
    $parts['query'] = http_build_query($queryParts);

    // return
    return http_build_url('', $parts);
}
```

Invocation should be:

```
$url = 'http://sitename.com/something/?inviter=1234&id=1';
$whitelist = [
    'inviter'
];
$expectedUrl = 'http://sitename.com/something/?inviter=1234';
$actualUrl = transformUrlKeepQueryKeys($url, $whitelist);
assert($expectedUrl == $actualUrl);
```

Alternatively, you could implement something similar using a blacklist of keys to remove.

The only problem with this is that the function `http_build_url` is not included in core PHP, but is part of the PECL HTTP extension. If you are unable to install that extension in your environment, then you can use a pure PHP implementation of that function, for example [here](https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url/blob/master/src/http_build_url.php).